# how to take the <html:text> in external javascript means js file in struts?

Tags: java, struts

if i want to set and retrieve value of  in struts.

Comment: Please give us more information on what do you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to include `<html:text />` in an external javascript file.

That's not possible as a servlet container doesn't iterate through a javascript file and replace JspTags in a javascript file to an html equivalent. This is **only** done on a jsp or jspx file.

Seeing I don't understand your question, I don't exactly know what to write.

Comment: i finding the solution i asked about <html:text property="username" >value, how to used it in javascript means to retrieve and set and solution is document.forms[0].username.value is used for that. and thanks for shown my question.

Comment: That's not possible @ all as Struts Tags generates html only tags and not javascript declarations.

Comment: it is possible i was checked it.

Comment: You cannot do struts tag on an external javascript file but you can do struts tag inside a `<script>` tag in the JSP file. That's the difference.

Comment: in js file we access the value of textfield using document.forms[0].username.value that is created in jsp like this <html:text property="username" >  i want to say that.

Comment: That is correct. I don't understand your question then, can you please clarify further.